# How to remove all the subset from a column except few based on the other column in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark data frame with a column of lists(column `a`) and another column with numbers(column `b`), I want to retain all are supersets rows, and subsets that have greater value in column b than their supersets.

For Example,

Input data frame:

```
Column a = ([A,B,C],[A,C],[B,C],[J,S,K],[J,S],[J,K])
Column b = (10,15,7,8,9,8)
```

Expected Outcome:

```
Column a = ([A,B,C],[A,C],[J,S,K],[J,S])
Column b = (10,15,8,9)
```

Here `[B,C]` and `[A,C]` are subsets of `[A,B,C]` but we only retain `[A,C]` because this subset has `15` in column `b` which is greater than `10` the supersets(`[A,B,C]`) value in column `b`.
Similarly, the superset `[J,S,K]` is retained along with its subset `[J,S]` because its value in column `b` is greater than the superset column `b` value.

Comment: you sample data are quite generic. Based on that, creating a generic solution is probably very difficult. On your real data, do you have a fixed size for **supersets** or it may vary ? Any ID to identify a superset, a subset or a group of sets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a self `left_anti` join to filter rows that satisfies that condition.

You'll need to have an `ID` column in your dataframe, here I'm using `monotonically_increasing_id` function to generate an `ID` for each row:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("ID", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df.show() 

#+---------+---+-----------+
#|        a|  b|         ID|
#+---------+---+-----------+
#|[A, B, C]| 10| 8589934592|
#|   [A, C]| 15|17179869184|
#|   [B, C]|  7|25769803776|
#|[J, S, K]|  8|42949672960|
#|   [J, S]|  9|51539607552|
#|   [J, K]|  8|60129542144|
#+---------+---+-----------+
```

Now, to verify an array `arr1` is a subset of another array `arr2`, you can use `array_intersect` and `size` functions `size(array_intersect(arr1, arr2)) = size(arr1)`:

```
df_result = df.alias("df1").join(
    df.alias("df2"),
    (
        (F.size(F.array_intersect("df1.a", "df2.a")) == F.size("df1.a"))
        & (F.col("df1.b") <= F.col("df2.b"))
        & (F.col("df1.ID") != F.col("df2.ID")) # not the same row
    ),
    "left_anti"
).drop("ID")

df_result.show()

#+---------+---+
#|        a|  b|
#+---------+---+
#|[A, B, C]| 10|
#|   [A, C]| 15|
#|[J, S, K]|  8|
#|   [J, S]|  9|
#+---------+---+
```